# After package upgrade, fresh install from yarn will break the node app

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

Trying my best to describe the issue,

yarn 1.22.19,
node 16.16.0,
MacOS

- start from an existing node app, everything was fine including unit
  tests
- yarn upgrade-interactive --latest (Note: i just picked a few for upgrade), i got the new package.json and new yarn.lock
- "yarn test" passes, this is for unit tests
- 
- rm -rf node_modules
- yarn install
- "yarn test" fails (similar to this https://github.com/iarna/wide-align/issues/63)
- Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /myApp/node_modules/string-width/index.js from /myApp/node_modules/cliui/build/index.cjs not supported.
- 
- revert back the yarn.lock, the only change now is package.json
- yarn install
- "yarn test" passes

so if i'm in a new system, start from the new package.json and the new yarn.lock, i cannot start my app. I need the old yarn.lock with the new package.json to do the proper install.
Do understand the node_modules are different from these 2 cases, but how to fix this pls ?

Comment: _"Similar"_ isn't good enough, please [edit] your question to provide details. If this is an issue with the `string-width` package (worst idea ever) there are a lot of existing Github issues and the general solution I've seen around is to upgrade to Yarn 3

Comment: Here's one issue with probably the most detail ~ https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/22431

Comment: @Phil thx for the info, but why i install from old yarn.lock and it doesn't break ?

Comment: This is an issue affecting Yarn v1 caused by some _questionable_ decisions in the cliui library. See https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4812. There's no good answer other than upgrade to Yarn v3

Answer (score 0):

Just as Phil suggested, upgrade to yarn v3 fixed the issue.